# Running Urho3D and Qt from main

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ipc, urho3d

I am using the Urho3D engine with Qt for an application. The problem is that both Urho3D and QApplication require to be ran from main(). For now I am using it in separate processes but IPC makes it complicated.
Is there any way to solve this issue? Thanks

My platform is Urho3D 1.5, Qt 4.71 and Windows 7 x64 and VS2015 (C++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is quite simple. Instead of running QApplication by calling

```
app->exec();
```

it is needed to manually and regularily call this from your main loop:

```
app->processEvents();
```

This will take care that all events used by Qt are processed and QApplication will respond accordingly.
Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <awidget.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    bool shallrun = true;
    aWidget *widget = new aWidget();
    widget->show();

    while (shallrun)
    {
       app->processEvents();
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to both c++ and Urho3D, but I've successfully achieved it.

Simple code, haven't had further test:

awidget.h:

```
#ifndef AWIDGET_H
#define AWIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <Urho3D/Engine/Application.h>
class aWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit aWidget(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(pressed()));
    }
public slots:
    void pressed()
    {
        Urho3D::Context* context = new Urho3D::Context();
        Urho3D::Application *application = new Urho3D::Application(context);
        application->Run();
    }
};
#endif // AWIDGET_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <awidget.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    aWidget *widget = new aWidget();
    widget->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

By the way, I'm using Qt 5.9.0

Comment: maybe its too simplified.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it, but thanks for the answer anyway. +1